# Vue string concatenation with values and conditional

Tags: vuejs2

Is there an option to display or hide a string based on a truthy value and when falsy it displays none, or can we only use ternary operator for this.

I know it is possible to do with class binding, where you add a value and then add the condition:

```
:class="{ 'class-only-if-true': false }"
```

so my question would be if it is possible to do the following only as a string:

```
{{'only display if true' : true}}
```

and possibly concatenate with data as such:

```
{{'only '+data+' if true' : true}}
```

While I know it would be possible adding a wrapper tag around this and adding the condition in here, but in this case I can't use any `<div>`, `<span>` or other.

While I could make it work as such (ternary operator):

```
{{ true ? 'only '+data+' if true' : ''}}
```

I was wondering if there would be an approach I have overlooked similar to the class binding condition.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ternary operator `{{ true ? 'only '+data+' if true' : ''}}`, you could use the `&&` operator like `{{ true && 'only '+data+' if true'}}`. Of course don't use `data` as it points to the components whole `data` object.